# Deleting Data with Relation using REST API | Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, rest

First of all I have `Book` DB field and `BookReview` DB field

[image: Book Field]
[image: BookReview]

Book Model:

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BookReview::class);
}
```

BookReview Model:

```
public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}
```

What I need to do is to delete a `BooksReview`, but it consists in a relationship with `Book` field

This is the route

```
Route::delete('/books/{bookId}/reviews/{reviewId}');
```

And this is the controller:

```
public function destroy(int $bookId, int $reviewId, Request $request)
{
    // TODO: implement
    $check_bookReview = BookReview::firstWhere('id', $reviewId);
    if ($check_bookReview) {
        BookReview::destroy($id);
        return response()->noContent();
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

I've never tried to delete data with a relation before, how do I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:❌

```php
public function destroy(int $bookId, int $reviewId, Request $request)
    {
        // @TODO implement
        $check_bookReview = BookReview::firstWhere('id', $reviewId);
        if ($check_bookReview) {
            BookReview::destroy($id);
            return response()->noContent();
        }
        else {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

Use this: ✅

```php
public function destroy(int $bookId, int $reviewId, Request $request)
{
    if (BookReview::destroy($reviewId)) {
        return response()->noContent();
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

[\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::destroy($ids)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2d6d02abc87edfc73a4b5154337c86c5933c5c8e/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1227) returns a total **count** of destroyed models for the given IDs.

Comment: its still returning 404Not Found

Comment: i'm able to use this as an answer, it was my mistake still using $id instead of $reviewId
thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding) to have Laravel automatically attempt to find and return the relevant models from your database based on the URI parameters defined in your route and associated function:

```
Route::delete('/books/{bookId}/reviews/{reviewId}', [BookReviewController::class, 'destroy');
```

```
public function destroy(Request $requst, Book $bookId, BookReview $reviewId)
{
    $bookId->delete();

    return response()->json([], 204);
}
```

Laravel will automatically attempt to find and return the relevant `Book` and `BookReview` models from the database based on the value of each parameter. If it can't find the relevant model it will fail with a `404` but otherwise, the value of each parameter will be that of a model. Note that the name of the parameters defined in the `Route` and function definitions must match for route model binding to work.

Comment: it's still returning 404 not found on my postman

Comment: @info.dava Have you defined the `route` correctly? Ensure you can see it by running `php artisan route:list` in your terminal. if you don't see it listed, then the route is wrong. Also ensure that you're providing the route with valid `bookId` and `reviewId` values that exist in the database. You'll get a `404` if Laravel can't find them.